# what is newtonsoft json version for breeze?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api2, breeze

I got error when run web api 2 project with breeze :

```
Error   2   Assembly 'Breeze.ContextProvider, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f6085f1a45e2ac59' uses 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
```

i tried other version but still error

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer, execute this on nuget package manager :

```
Uninstall-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Force
```

and after that :`Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 9.0.1`